# Error: lidar is not defined in SDF, ignoring lidar

Tags: gazebo, sdformat, gazebo-7

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello. I'm new to Gazebo and I'm trying to create a 2D-lidar sensor and connect in later on with ROS. Following the tutorial [http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?cat=guided_i&tut=guided_i1] I created the following world file, but instead of ray element I use lidar.
[image: image description]

When I run the world file I get the error:

```
Warning [parser.cc:778] XML Element[lidar], child of element[sensor] not defined in SDF. Ignoring[lidar]. You may have an incorrect SDF file, or an sdformat version that doesn't support this element.
```

When I change the above file to use ray element it runs smoothly. I follow the SDF format from here:
[link text](http://sdformat.org/spec?ver=1.7&elem=sensor#sensor_lidar) so I don't know where the problem might be. Can anyone tell me what I'm missing here?

I use Ubuntu 16.04 and the pre-installed Gazebo 7 and i would prefer to stay with this version. Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/25796/error:-lidar-is-not-defined-in-sdf,-ignoring-lidar/) by [Meanmachine](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/32360/meanmachine/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-09-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

This error means that your SDF is not well formed.

You can find some test worlds in the [gazebo_ros_pkgs repository](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/tree/kinetic-devel/gazebo_plugins/test/test_worlds) that can help to build your own model/world. For example to include a lidar you can review this [file](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/blob/kinetic-devel/gazebo_plugins/test/test_worlds/gazebo_ros_gpu_laser.world).

Regards

---

Originally posted by [ahcorde](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/26408/ahcorde/) with karma: 281 on 2020-09-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Meanmachine](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/32360/meanmachine/) on 2020-09-19**:
Thanks! That helps